# how to bind class name from a json file using Angular [ngClass]

Tags: angular, ng-class

I have a json file contains a icons object like this:

```
"icons" : {
        "logo" : "fa fa-caret-down",
        "search" : "fas fa-search",
        "bell" : "far fa-bell"
    }
```

In my component.ts, I am able to get this icons object using a service successfully like this:

```
navIcons: object;
   getNavIcons(): void {
    this.navbarService.getNavIcons()
    .subscribe(navIcons => {
      this.navIcons = navIcons;
      console.log(this.navIcons)
    //   icons : {
    //     logo : "fa fa-caret-down",
    //     search : "fas fa-search",
    //     bell : "far fa-bell"
    // }
    });
  }
```

How can I bind thoes class in the component.html template? I tried like this:

```
 <i id="logo" [ngClass]="['navIcons.logo']" class="nav-icon"></i>
```

but it failed. I also have another calss: nav-icon need to added into this logo? Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Try this [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) syntax :

```
[ngClass]="navIcons?.logo"
```

Since `navIcons` is initially `undefined`, use the safe navigation operator `?.` to prevent the exception when trying to access the `logo` property.